# Screenshot taken by the Application is blank on Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Hi,

We have a C# application which captures a screenshot of desktop. It works well on windows XP but on vista the screenshot picture is blank. Why so ?? Any solution to this ?

Comment: We need more details, how is your application taking a screen shot?

Comment: It might be helpful to know which application it is...

Answer (score 0):

This should go to stackoverflow; the reason is that the UI programming model radically changed between XP and Vista and you'll be able to get some good help over there.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of UAC it uses different desktop to display itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please post code to help you out. I wrote an [article about screenshot](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=303) (VB.net and c#) sometime back.It works fine in XP and Vista. Check it out if interested.

How are you capturing it? Is the screensize different?